# My 11.3MB database file takes 3 minutes to load with Pickle

Tags: python, pickle, solid-state-drive

I have a very large database/dictionary of movie ratings by random users which totals to around 400,000 items in total. I use pickle to store it in a .p file in the same directory. When pressing the run button in my Enthought Canopy IDE, it takes over 3 minutes to load the 11.3MB file, when let's say, a 1GB video can load and start in seconds.

That's on a 2TB 7200RPM hard drive. On a Samsung 850 EVO SSD, it takes about the same, or longer. What could be causing this? My IDE? Pickle?
I have Python 2.7.

I'm using this to read:

```
import cPickle as pickle
ratings = pickle.load( open( ratings_database_file, "rb" ) )
```

Comment: If you can, make sure you're using [`cPickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle), which can be up to 1000x faster than `pickle`.

Comment: Nope, using normal pickle. That's probably it. Do I just replace all 'pickle's with 'cpickle', or is there different syntax?

Comment: Presumably you have `import pickle` somewhere, right? Use `import cPickle as pickle` instead, then the rest of the code can stay the same.

Comment: Important qualification: this only works on Python 2.x. In Python 3, `import pickle` automatically imports the C version.

Comment: `cPickle` is a C based pickle for python 2. If you are using python 3, the regular `pickle` module will call the optimzed C version automatically when available. Make sure not to use the default pickle protocol when dumping the data in the first place - it is backwards compatible with ancient Egyptian writing but dulls your chisel. Use protocol 2 with python 2 and and 3 or 4 with python 3. ... and try the load outside of your IDE to see if its too clever for its own good.

Comment: If your pickled file is that large you might want to start looking into using an actual database like sqlite.

Comment: @jayelm Even after dumping to the file with cPickle, it still loads as slow as before. On Python 2.7

Comment: I created a 400,000 list of dicts that pickled to 31Meg with protocol 0 and 16Meg with protocol 2. Time to load on my decidedly underpowered notebook were 1.97 seconds and 0.98 seconds respectively. Your problem is elsewhere! I find that IDE more suspicious all the time.

Comment: @TrivisionZero it's not dumping that matters (cPickle and pickle use the same format). It's loading with `cPickle` that matters. In that case, you still don't observe a speedup?

Comment: You are using python 2.7 (my tests were with 3.4) so I went back and did more timing. `pickle.load` with protocol 2 was 15 seconds. `cPickle.load` was 1.5 seconds. With protocol 0 pickle was 17 seconds and cPickle was 4.2 seconds. Did you by chance print the data to the screen as you loaded? That is just did `pickle.load(...)` at the prompt instead of assigning it to a varible (e.g., `foo = pickle.load(...)`)?

Comment: Yes, I assigned it to a variable.

Comment: @jayelm Nope, dumps in a second, takes 3 minutes to load.

Comment: Weird, when the code to read to variable is executed in the console, it loads in 2 seconds, but when it's in the actual code? 3 minutes...

Comment: Actually nevermind, there was this weird code at the very far bottom not in a function and it was executing every time I hit run. I placed random prints to find where it was being held up, and the weird thing was that it never printed *after* the pickle statement, that's why I thought it might have been pickle. Turns out it only takes two seconds. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing a large video file doesn't typically read the whole file into memory at once - the media player will buffer enough to start displaying it and then stream more as it needs it. If you want your database to be snappier, you could store it differently, so that it doesn't need to load everything into memory to start with - something like a much smaller index as a tree with offsets into the data records.

That said, 3 minutes does sound extreme. Some things you could try to make it faster:

- Use [`cPickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) if you're using Python 2, as a comment suggests (Python 3 does this automatically).
- Make sure you're using the latest binary pickle format.
- [Profile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/profile.html) the loading - unpickling objects can call methods on the objects as it loads them (depending on the classes) and it might be that they're doing work you're not expecting. I've found [snakevis](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) or [RunSnakeRun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) useful for exploring the profiler output.
- Another way to explore this would be to change the format of the objects you're storing - pickle it as a list of tuples, or even write it out as (gzipped) JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the entire dictionary of ratings at the same time in memory, you might think about storing the dict to a database, or a 'on-disk' database composed of a set of files.  I'm the author of `klepto`, which is well-suited for this purpose -- it provides a python dictionary abstract interface to a SQL database, or a directory of files on disk; both seem like they'd fit your purpose.

In short, you can either have a direct interaction with the database (`cached=False`) or one that is buffered by an in-memory dictionary (`cached=True`).

To build an archive:

```
>>> import klepto
>>> d = klepto.archives.dir_archive('ratings', serialized=True)
>>> d['Dune'] = 10
>>> d['Monty Python'] = 9
>>> d['Avengers'] = 2
>>> d.dump()
```

To read an entry or an archive:

```
>>> import klepto
>>> d = klepto.archives.dir_archive('ratings', serialized=True)
>>> d.load('Dune')
>>> d
dir_archive('ratings', {'Dune': 10}, cached=True)
>>> d['Dune']
10
>>> d.load()
>>> d.keys()
['Monty Python', 'Avengers', 'Dune']
>>> d.items()
[('Monty Python', 9), ('Avengers', 2), ('Dune', 10)]
>>>
```

It should load much faster if you don't need all the entries.  A second bonus is that you can very easily experiment with different encodings and storage formats, to see what works best for your needs.